Do California's whistleblower protections apply to non-employees and private businesses?
In California, do the whistleblower's protections apply to non-employees and private businesses?
For example, suppose you live in a small town with a single gas station. And you notice that its employee was smoking (which you are not supposed to do at a gas station). You write to the management. But the management accuses you of lying, hints that it will sue you if you tell anyone else, and further retaliates by banning you. Is that legal?

Why is the employee not allowed to smoke?

I don't think a person who is not an employee can be a whistleblower. That said, whistleblower protections do apply to private businesses (e.g. via Dodd-Frank) but only if they go to the relevant authorities for reporting the information (e.g. the SEC).

@JonCuster It's a fire hazard at a gas station.

@Barmar - that depends a lot on where they smoke. Somehow in the 1960s and 70s people smoked in gas stations all the time. They didn't throw burning matches and cigarettes into gas containers (you could throw them into diesel containers though). So, what is the law about smoking or not.

@JonCuster I've been googling, and finding a variety of regulations (depending on jurisdiction) that specify a safe distance from the pumps. And a technical site mentions that gas vapors can be ignited, so it's not just where you throw away the matches and butts.

@Barmar As far as I am aware there are not any laws/rules preventing people from smoking at a gas station. There are just rules about specific areas that you can't smoke at. For example you can smoke at the side of the building that is away from the fueling area but you can't smoke in the fueling area itself.

@JoeW Like I said: "safe distance from the pumps". If you're too close to the pumps it's a safety hazard.

@JonCuster IMHO the smoking is just a place holder for some bad/dangerous behavior

IMHO Whistleblower protections are there to protect employees from retribution from their place of work when they identify Bad Things© going on there.  As the John Doe is not an employee, him noticing the employee smoking means that he is simply a witness to the event and not a whistleblower.
As such the management of the company are free to threaten lawsuits etc any time of the day.  However, if the management went down that path, they would potentially open themselves up to accusations that they are starting a SLAPP lawsuit.  Thus, Mr Doe could gain protection in that arena.

Strategic lawsuits against public participation (also known as SLAPP
suits or intimidation lawsuits),1 or strategic litigation against
public participation,[2] are lawsuits intended to censor, intimidate,
and silence critics by burdening them with the cost of a legal defense
until they abandon their criticism or opposition.[3]

From the same link:

California
California has a unique variant of anti-SLAPP legislation. In 1992
California enacted Code of Civil Procedure § 425.16, a statute
intended to frustrate SLAPPs by providing a quick and inexpensive
defense.[11] It provides for a special motion that a defendant can
file at the outset of a lawsuit to strike a complaint when it arises
from conduct that falls within the rights of petition or free speech.
The statute expressly applies to any writing or speech made in
connection with an issue under consideration or review by a
legislative, executive, or judicial proceeding, or any other official
proceeding authorized by law, but there is no requirement that the
writing or speech be promulgated directly to the official body. It
also applies to speech in a public forum about an issue of public
interest and to any other petition or speech conduct about an issue of
public interest.

